# Je pensais jamais qu'il irait lui dire

Tags: passé-composé, imparfait

*De L.A. à Laval* d'Alexandra Larochelle :

> MOI : T'avais dit ça pour vrai ?
>
> ANTHONIE : Ben... oui, mais je **pensais** **jamais** qu'il irait lui dire !

Je pensais avant qu'il fallait employer le passé composé dans les phrases contenant *jamais* au lieu de *pas*. Je ne comprends pas pourquoi l'auteure emploie l'imparfait ici.

Comment: Cet écrivain québecois est francophone. Donc, on peut supposer que son français est complètement idiomatique.

Comment: @Lambie … et qu'Anthonie parle un français idiomatique,  c'est à dire  que l'auteur a choisi pour ce caractère un français idiomatique ?

Comment: There is a famous song called [« Je pensais pas »](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmudHbgHOLc) by Daniel Lavoie (Franco-Manitobain) whose chorus runs: « Je pensais pas qu'un jour j'aimerais si fort / que penser de partir serait comme penser de mourir. »

Comment: @LukeSawczak Dans mon exemple, il y a _je pensais **jamais**_. C'est ce _jamais_ qui change tout pour moi. Quand on dit _je pensais pas_, il s'agit d'une habitude, d'une répétition. Ou _Le gars que je fréquentais ne me **laissait jamais** payer pour quoi que ce soit._ [lien](https://www.reddit.com/r/French/comments/iex29g/is_ne_jamais_incompatible_with_limparfait/). Dans mon exemple, la logique est différente.

Comment: @Oreste Ah, oui. Je vois. Toutefois je ne pense pas que *jamais* change vraiment le cas ici. Quand une chose n'a jamais eu lieu il importe que peu whether it didn't happen once or didn't ever happen :) It's an unreality either time.

Comment: @LukeSawczak _il importe peu whether it didn't happen once or didn't ever happen :)_ Oui, en russe aussi. Mais en français si, je crois. Je l'ai lu quelque part, mais ne trouve plus le lien. Je suis d'accord avec LPH, les 3 premières phrases devraient être employées dans un "français standard". Mais la phrase _Quand j'étais enfant, je ne **pensais jamais** aux fantômes_ serait correcte partout, car il s'agit d'une habitude. Quoique j'utiliserais _pas_ là.

Comment: @Oreste *Je suis d'accord avec LPH, les 3 premières phrases devraient être employées dans un "français standard".* Oh non ! Tu penses vraiment ça ? Mais il s'agit d'un dialogue. Il peut quand même essayer de transmettre la réalité des personnages, les faire vivre, non ? Quelle tristesse si toute la francophonie **parlait** "parisien".

Comment: @jlliagre Non, bien sûr que dans les livres québécois, les personnages devraient parler comme les gens parlent ici. Mais je disais autre chose. J'ai compris que ce tour est correct ici. Le problème est que lorsque je communique avec des Français qui vivent en France, ceux-ci s'attendent à ce que j'écrive dans le français qu'ils emploient. Donc, je disais qu'à l'écrit, ce tour paraitrait bizarre aux Français. Mon but était de savoir s'il était possible de l'utiliser à l'écrit en France.

Comment: _Quelle tristesse si toute la francophonie parlait "parisien"._ Je suis d'accord. Mais je trouve la distinction entre le PC et l'imparfait pas évidente, et je voulais d'abord connaitre les règles de base.

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit d'un dialogue en français québécois parlé qu'il n'y a aucune raison de mettre en doute. Il n'est pas inconcevable que quelqu'un puisse dire la même chose en France (un rare exemple ici: [audio: [G. Hamel sur François Fillon]](https://intensite.net/2009/sites/default/files/161122_hamel_fillon_2.mp3) - *Je pensais jamais qu'il serait à ce niveau de score* Source: [intensité.net](https://intensite.net/2009/actu2016/eure-et-loir-je-pensais-jamais-qu-il-serait-a-ce-niveau-de-score-ghamel-244880)) mais on s'attend ici à :

> *ANTHONIE : Ben... oui, mais **j'aurais jamais pensé** qu'il irait lui dire !*

J'ai trouvé une autre occurrence de ce tour, là aussi d'un auteur québécois:

> *Je sais que c'est stupide de ma part, mais **je pensais jamais** qu'y ferait quelque chose comme ça.* Éric Chassé, *Ils étaient deux*, 2018.

Sur Internet, la très grande majorité des occurrences de "*je pensais jamais **que** [...]*" provient de sources québécoises. En revanche, les formes *je pensais jamais + **infinitif*** et *je pensais jamais + **à** [...]* sont courantes en France aussi :

> *Je pensais jamais te revoir*
> *Je pensais jamais à elle*

Dans le premier exemple, l'adverbe *jamais* s'applique au complément, pas au verbe penser.

D'autre part, "*dire pour vrai*" est aussi un québécisme. Il ne s'entend pas du tout en France où on dit :

> *MOI : T'avais dit ça pour **de** vrai ?*

Comment: Peut-être que je me suis mal exprimée, c'est surtout que je ne comprends pas cet usage. Je vais modifier ma question. J'aurais écrit _j'avais jamais pensé_ ou _j'aurais jamais pensé_. Je crois que les deux options sont correctes, non ? // _Je pensais jamais te revoir_ et _Je pensais jamais à elle_ ont une autre structure, je la comprends mieux. // J'ai lu _pour de vrai_, je n'ai pas remarqué l'omission de _de_. [pour vrai](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pour_vrai)

Comment: Dans ta question, tu écris *Je pensais avant qu'il faudrait employer le passé composé dans la phrase qui contient jamais au lieu de pas*. Ce serait plus idiomatique comme ça : *Je croyais qu'il fallait employer le passé composé dans les phrases contenant jamais au lieu de pas*.

Comment: OK, mais il est aussi possible d'employer _Je pensais que_ au lieu de _je croyais que_ ?

Comment: Oui, on peut utiliser l'un ou l'autre dans ce cas.

Answer (score 1):

Non, l'imparfait n'est pas correct si l'on considère le contexte le plus courant, c'est à dire un contexte où l'action (en fait l'état) a une seule  occurrence ; il faut soit le passé composé soit le  plus que parfait, ou encore le conditionnel passé ; en français littéraire le passé du conditionnel seconde forme est aussi possible. Le choix dépend du contexte.

- oui, mais je n'ai jamais pensé qu'il irait lui dire !
- oui, mais je n'avais jamais pensé qu'il irait lui dire !
- oui, mais je n'aurais jamais pensé qu'il irait lui dire !
- oui, mais je n'eusse jamais pensé qu'il irait lui dire !

La raison pour ne pas pouvoir utiliser l'imparfait se trouve dans le sens du verbe, qui ne peut être que le verbe statif suivant.

> (TLFi) **B.** − [Le compl. est une prop.]
> **1.** [Prop. complét. ou à valeur de complét.]
> **a)** Penser que.[Suivi de l'ind. si la princ. est positive, de l'ind. ou du subj. si la princ. est nég., interr. ou si penser figure dans une hypothétique]
> **β)** Synon. de croire, supposer (que) ou de avoir le sentiment, l'impression (que).

Cependant, si on  utilise un imparfait descriptif, c'est à dire un imparfait qui situe le cadre d'une action, la phrase reste correcte mais le sens change et ne correspond plus au contexte d'état qui ne change pas ; on a maintenant un contexte d'états successifs qui sont une répétition d'un même et seul état, celui de croire.

- oui, mais je croyais jamais qu'il irait lui dire !

« Penser que » c'est « croire », donc si on ne « croyait jamais » il est nécessaire que cela soit arrivé à plusieurs reprises, ce qui ne se trouve pas dans les contextes courants.
Cependant « penser à » signifie « avoir à l'esprit » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/penser) : Avoir présent à l'esprit (une idée, une image, un sentiment, un projet))

En changeant le verbe l'imparfait est correct.

- oui, mais je **pensais** jamais **au** fait qu'il irait lui dire !

Comment: Cela se voit et cela s'entend: "Quand ça nous arrive on y croit pas. Je pensais jamais vivre une telle crise sanitaire" dit Pierre Deladonchamps .  • © Pierre Deladonchamps pour France Télévisions https://france3-regions.francetvinfo.fr/grand-est/meurthe-et-moselle/nancy/confinement-acteur-pierre-deladonchamps-parfois-fiction-n-est-pas-hauteur-realite-1807490.html

Comment: @Lambie C'est une tournure un peu différente où *jamais* modifie un infinitif, pas le verbe penser : *Je pensais [**ne**] jamais vivre une telle crise sanitaire*.

Comment: @jlliagre Ouais, pour la crise sanitaire, il y avait aussi: "C'était surréaliste, **je ne pensais jamais vivre une telle crise sanitaire**." une phrase citée sur plusieurs sites.

Comment: Dans la phrase _Oui, mais je croyais jamais qu'il irait lui dire !_ il est possible de remplacer _je croyais_ par _je pensais_, non ? Je veux dire que si nous parlons d'une habitude, d'une répétition, il est possible d'employer ces deux verbes, indifféremment. Par exemple, la phrase _Quand j'étais enfant, je pensais jamais aux fantômes_, mais là j'écrirais _Quand j'étais enfant, je n'ai jamais cru aux fantômes_.

Comment: @Oreste Oui, c'est exact, on peut les employer indifféremment, mais du point de vue des nuances que le contexte renferme, l'un peut être préférable à l'autre ; par exemple, dans un contexte dans lequel le fait de croire est déduit plus ou moins à partir de stades assez logiques, un auteur pourrait préférer le verbe « croire », peut-être pour insister sur cette idée de déduction assez factuelle.   « Quand j'étais enfant, je pensais jamais aux fantômes » n'a rien à voir avec « croire » ; en fait lorsqu'on vous dit ça, il vous vient l'idée que cette personne croirait vraiment  aux phantômes.